# autolayout instead of autoresizingMask

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

How can i write the *following* code **using NSLayoutConstraints** (or **anchors**) in a *UIView subclass*?

```
func commonInit() {
    aView                  = UIView()
    aView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

    addSubview(aView)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let smallerSide = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)

    aView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: smallerSide, height: smallerSide)
    aView.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
}
```

One objective is to *avoid* using `layoutSubviews()`. 
Also, the `aView` must maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio.
If you'd need any more info, please let me know.

PS: Please let's use *swift3*, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let viewsDict = ["view": view]
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    addSubview(view)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it has a few problems: view has to be added as a subview before constraints can be added. And my aim is to not fill the subclass with another view - but to have a square in the center, with 1:1 side ratios.

Comment: @This just fills the super view. Not what OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

I have replicated the same behaviour via size classes, but only for iPhones. Check this storyboard. (Its not code, what you asked for)

[Storyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5iizibv9ul5f8t/Main%2840802240%29.storyboard?dl=0)

Since iPads have width:Regaular and Height:Regular, it seems it is not possible for iPads, without using `layoutSubview`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works as you mentioned and for a single / few controllers. Unfortunately my goal is to reuse that subclass a lot (as a background or something else) – to be able to keep them all up to date, it should be subclassed.